# How to get a file from rails-api which using carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, rails-api

I have a rails-api project, which provide the api to access my data.

I use carrierwave to store my file, my model called `User` and file attribute called `image`.

So, the image attribute contained the `file_name`, `url` and some other info.

In order to translate the file through the api, I added the gem `carrierwave-base64`.

I understand the **Upload** process. The client app encode the file to `base64 code`, then sent to backend by a json message. For example:

```
{user: {email: "test@email.com", image: "data:image/jpg;base64,#{base64_image}"}
```

So when the backend receive the json request, the carrierwave will parse the base64 code to a file and store it to local or S3

**What I do not understand, is the `Download` process:**

When I request the user info, what I assume is that the image file would be transfered as a `base64 code` in a json message, and then the client app will encode the `base64 code` to a file(image), and then display.

But actually, what I can provide for the json data, is the file url, not the base64 code.

The reason I want to get the file(image) from the api-server is because I don't want to the client app directly access s3 by url. So every time when the client app want to get a file, it will request the api-server, and api-server will get the file and transfer to the client.

Does anyone can explain how to do the download?

Or if I was thought in a wrong strategy, that I need another api endpoint to response a file object, not just accompany with user model.

Cheers.

Comment: you did a good thing with uploading ,But while downloading you need to send URL no base64, That is what I am doing in my project and its traditional  and good way to do this is put read public permission on s3 while uploading and use expiring_url(60, :thumb) for your clients

Answer (score 0):

Restricting Access to Objects Stored on Amazon S3

```
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Restricting-Access-to-Objects-Stored-on-Amazon-S3
```

you did a good thing with uploading ,But while downloading you need to send URL no base64 and its traditional
Also for securrity purpose you can put  public read permission on s3 while uploading and use expiring_url(60, :thumb) for your clients

In this URL get expired in time that you have specified